# How can I use spring RestTemplate to make a test request against the Cloudant API?

Tags: resttemplate, cloudant

I'm looking for some guidance to execute a basic API call against Cloudant using Spring RestTemplate.

Here are some assumptions:

- I know how to program in Java
- I know how to use [Cloudant's API](https://docs.cloudant.com/)
- I need to use Spring
  [RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

However, I'm not sure how to get started using RestTemplate with Cloudant.  For example, is there a basic Cloudant API call that I can use to test connectivity and return a result set?

Comment: **downvoters:**  If you downvote this question, please tell me why so that I can improve the question.

Comment: If you know how to use the components, what "basic guidance" do you want? What problem do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Hopefully the question is clearer now?

Comment: Better, but it's still unclear. If you're asking how to make a test request to the API, then ask that specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example shows you how you can make a basic call against Cloudant using Cloudant Education's example database.

```java
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Application {

    private final static String URL = 
        "https://education.cloudant.com/animaldb/_design/views101/_view/latin_name?include_docs=true";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // Normally you would bind the response to Java domain objects and not String
        // See https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/ for examples of binding 
        // response objects to Java domain objects

        String animals = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, String.class);

        System.out.println(animals);
    }
}
```

You should see some output similar to this:

```
...
{
  "total_rows": 5,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "kookaburra",
      "key": "Dacelo novaeguineae",
      "value": 19,
      "doc": {
        "_id": "kookaburra",
        "_rev": "4-6038cf35dfe1211f85484dec951142c7",
        "min_length": 0.28,
        "max_length": 0.42,
        "wiki_page": "http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Kookaburra",
        "class": "bird",
        "diet": "carnivore",
        "latin_name": "Dacelo novaeguineae"
      }
    },
    ... 
  ]
}
...
```

**NOTE**:

- There is an example project [on github](https://github.com/snowch/cloudant-resttemplate-example) to help you get started.
- You can hit the URL in your browser to see the raw json: https://education.cloudant.com/animaldb/_design/views101/_view/latin_name?include_docs=true